# Landscape orientation on Media pipe Android App.. The camera orientation is wrong once the app is set in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, pose-estimation, mediapipe

I created media pipe android app. And remove the restrictions so that it can work in landscape. But the camera is rotated by 90 degrees in landscape mode. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, You'll need to modify 3 files. I couldn't get it to work with Auto rotate but its working perfectly if you need it to be always on landscape. Look at the steps I mentioned here: https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/568#issuecomment-975439977

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70068587/edit) your answer and add the solution if possible, in case the link breaks. Thanks.